# Trying to autoselect option box based on users OS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

So I have a live website here: http://www.trock.net/#/downloads

What I am trying to do is preselect the "select operating system" option based on the users OS.

The apps.js is located here:
http://www.trock.net/js/app.js.

The raw HTML for the download page is located here: www.trock.net/includes/downloads.html

Now, the issue is that the detectOS function I have does not seem to work. I have tried attaching it to `ng-init` on the app and `ng-init` on a div after the select box but that does not work. If I attach `ng-click` and click it, it works as expected.

Each option has an ID which is what I am using to find the element so I can set 'selected' to true. Is there a better way of doing this using angular?

How would I go about making this work, is the issue that I am calling the function too early or perhaps too late?

Code of interest in apps.js:

```
//Auto select Operating System based on detection
  $scope.detectOS = function() {
    var processorArchitecture = "";
    var userOS = "";

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("WOW64") != -1 || 
      navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win64") != -1 ){
     processorArchitecture = "64";
    } else { //Assume 32 bit
     processorArchitecture = "32";
    }

    //Detect the OS
    if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1){
     userOS = "win";

     if (processorArchitecture == "64")
      processorArchitecture = "32";
    } 
    else if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac") != -1){
     userOS = "mac";

     if (processorArchitecture == "64")
      processorArchitecture = "32";
    } 
    else if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Lin") != -1){
     userOS = "lin";
    }

    //Check for valid detection
    if (userOS != "" && processorArchitecture != "") {
      //Valid match found
      var optionSelectionID = userOS + processorArchitecture;

      //Auto detect OS
      //We will find only 1 instance of said query
      angular.element( document.querySelector( "#win32") )[0].selected = true;
    }

  };
```

I also made a plunker which actually works so it must be something else I am doing on the website (perhaps loading in other .html pages ajax style).

Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/zlmk24aVHeBNz79PjypP?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I solved the issue, it seems that the presence of the `ng-model` was stopping the above code from working. Removing it means it worked fine but I needed the `ng-model` set to do other things.

Anyway, I ended up using the `ng-options` derivative like so to solve my problem:

```
<select ng-model="operatingSystemID" ng-options="os as os.label for os in osList track by os.id" id="download-dropdown">
```

I used this as my osList:

```
  //Create supported operating systems list
  $scope.osList = [
    {
      id: "win32",
      label: "Windows (32/64 bit)"
    },
    {
      id: "mac32",
      label: "Mac OS (32/64 bit)"
    },
    {
      id: "lin32",
      label: "Linux (32 bit)"
    },
    {
      id: "lin64",
      label: "Linux (64 bit)"
    }
  ];
```

And this was my new detectOS function:

```
$scope.detectOS = function() {
    var processorArchitecture = "";
    var processorArchitectureCompat = "";
    var userOS = "";
    var userOSNicename = "";

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("WOW64") != -1 || 
      navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win64") != -1 ){
     processorArchitecture = "64";
    } else { //Assume 32 bit
     processorArchitecture = "32";
    }

    processorArchitectureCompat = processorArchitecture;

    //Detect the OS
    if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1){
     userOS = "win";
     userOSNicename = "Windows";

     if (processorArchitecture == "64")
      processorArchitectureCompat = "32";
    } 
    else if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac") != -1){
     userOS = "mac";
     userOSNicename = "Mac OS";

     if (processorArchitecture == "64")
      processorArchitectureCompat = "32";
    } 
    else if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Lin") != -1){
      userOS = "lin";
      userOSNicename = "Linux";
    }

    //Check for valid detection
    if (userOS != "" && processorArchitecture != "") {
      //Valid match found
      var optionSelectionID = userOS + processorArchitectureCompat;

      //Output detected option to os message section
      $scope.os_detection_box =  $sce.trustAsHtml("(We have detected your OS as " + userOSNicename + " " +processorArchitecture + " bits)");

      //Auto select the detected option
      $scope.operatingSystemID = {id: optionSelectionID};
    }
  };
```